# Block window maximize functionality? (Completely)

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I am trying to create a window with behavior similar to **cmd.exe**, specifically whereby I don't want to support maximizing the window, since I only show fully visible lines of text (vertically). I have come up with two solutions so far:

Solution 1:

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            if (wParam == SC_MAXIMIZE) {
                return 0;
            }
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
```

Solution 2:

```
case WM_SIZE:
        if (wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED) {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
```

Unfortunately, the former is only effective if the user explicitly clicks the maximize button in the title bar, or in a context menu. It won't block it if the user simply double clicks the title bar for example.

The problem with the latter solution, for me, is that it causes scrollbars to disappear until you resize the window manually (by dragging the sides). Also, you can sometimes see the window flash before the window size is restored (I did try disabling redrawing before sending `WM_SYSCOMMAND`/`SC_RESTORE`, but unfortunately it did not help much).

Is there a better solution that I'm missing?

Comment: why not remove WS_MAXIMIZEBOX from the window style?

Comment: Anyway, your solution #2 is very bad idea.

Comment: Besides the point, but *cmd.exe* **can** be maximized (at least on Windows 10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
    UINT SysCommandCode = wParam & 0xFFF0;
    if (SysCommandCode == SC_MAXIMIZE) {
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```

Also it is recommended to remove WS_MAXIMIZEBOX from the windows style (when creating).

Comment: Totally overlooked the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style. That did the trick. Thanks!